# Exception evaluating SpringEL expression: "_csrf.token" with Get request

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, thymeleaf, junit5, mockmvc

I have a spring boot 2.5.1 application having spring security and thymleaf.

In order to pass csrf token, i followed the spring documentation link https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.0.x/reference/html/csrf.html#csrf-include-csrf-token-ajax

index.html contain header as mentioned in above link

```
<meta name="_csrf" th:content="${_csrf.token}"/>
<meta name="_csrf_header" th:content="${_csrf.headerName}"/>
```

and below is the configuration to include token with all ajax requests

```
$(function () {
    var token = $("meta[name='_csrf']").attr("content");
    var header = $("meta[name='_csrf_header']").attr("content");
    $(document).ajaxSend(function (e, xhr, options) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader(header, token);
    });
});
```

However, after adding above changes, existing junit test case started failing

```
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
@WebMvcTest(MyUserInterfaceController.class)
class MyUserInterfaceControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Test
    void shouldGetIndexPageWithNoUnknownUserName() throws Exception {
        mockMvc.perform(get("/"))
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andExpect(view().name("index"))
                .andExpect(model().attribute("username", "UNKNOWN_USER"));
    }
}
```

Above testcase was passing until I made csrf related changes. However, below test case is passing with or without csrf changes.

```
    @SneakyThrows
    @Test
    @WithMockTestUser
    void shouldSaveSettlementRemark() {
        //var userDtos= ...
        mockMvc.perform(post("/users")
                .contentType(APPLICATION_JSON)
                .content(userDtos))
                .andDo(print())
                .andExpect(status().isOk());
    }
```

As per spring documentation if spring security jar is in classpath , csrf is enabled by default & hence post requests expects csrf token otherwise request is forbidden. Testcases written using MockMvc are not adhering to this behaviour.

**Why GET request is failing with below stacktrace while POST request is passing ? How to fix this?**

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Exception evaluating SpringEL expression: "_csrf.token" (template: "index" - line 6, col 24)

    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1014)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:626)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
    at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.TestDispatcherServlet.service(TestDispatcherServlet.java:72)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:733)
    at org.springframework.mock.web.MockFilterChain$ServletFilterProxy.doFilter(MockFilterChain.java:167)
    at org.springframework.mock.web.MockFilterChain.doFilter(MockFilterChain.java:134)
```

On running application , UI is being rendered but at backend , even when no user requests are initiated, thymeleaf is trying to render index.html which is throwing below error.

```
":"org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine","message":"[THYMELEAF][http-nio-8080-exec-1] Exception processing template \"index\": An error happened during template parsing (template: \"templates/index.html\")","stack_trace":"<#24d6b41b> o.s.e.s.SpelEvaluationException: EL1007E: Property or field 'token' cannot be found on null\n\tat o.s.e.s.a.PropertyOrFieldReference.readProperty(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:213)
```

Both the above error I can fix by adding a null check as below:

**Is this right approach or am i compromising with security of application?**

```
<meta name="_csrf" th:content="${_csrf != null} ? ${_csrf.token} : '' "/>
<meta name="_csrf_header" th:content="${_csrf != null} ? ${_csrf.headerName} : '' "/>
```

WebSecurity configuration as below:

```
@Slf4j
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private final CustomProperties customProperties;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        if (customProperties.isEnabled()) {
            log.info("authentication enabled.");
            http.authorizeRequests()
                    .anyRequest()
                    .authenticated()
                    .and()
                    .oauth2Login()
                    .redirectionEndpoint()
                    .baseUri(customProperties.getAuthorizationResponseUri())
                    .and()
                    .userInfoEndpoint(userInfo -> userInfo.userService(new CustomOAuth2UserService()::loadUser));
        } else {
            log.info("authentication disabled.");
            http.authorizeRequests()
                    .anyRequest()
                    .permitAll();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How does your security configuration look like? And do you import the configuration bean in your `@WebMvcTest` tests?

Comment: @WimDeblauwe Added the code of web security configuration and i have not imported that context in @ WebMvcTest

Answer (score 1):

By default, when csrf is enabled, Spring Security generates the csrf token when a session is started. If you have no session there will be no csrf token to be had. Your second test uses an authenticated user, will have a session, and succeeds.

You can use the following meta tags to handle this situation and when csrf is disabled:

```
<meta sec:authorize="isFullyAuthenticated()" th:if="${_csrf}" name="_csrf" th:content="${_csrf.token}"/>
<meta sec:authorize="isFullyAuthenticated()" th:if="${_csrf}" name="_csrf_header" th:content="${_csrf.headerName}"/>
<meta sec:authorize="isFullyAuthenticated()" th:if="${_csrf}" name="_csrf_parameter" th:content="${_csrf.parameterName}"/>
```

An alternative is to change the csrf token strategy in your configuration:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests()
    // other security information ...
   .and().csrf().csrfTokenRepository(new HttpSessionCsrfTokenRepository())
}
```

And to use the following meta tags:

```
<meta name="_csrf" th:content="${_csrf.token}"/>
<meta name="_csrf_header" th:content="${_csrf.headerName}"/>
<meta name="_csrf_parameter" th:content="${_csrf.parameterName}"/>
```

I'm not sure why your POST is working though. With csrf enabled I would think you would have to use the .with(csrf()) as shown below.

```
@SneakyThrows
@Test
@WithMockTestUser
void shouldSaveSettlementRemark() {
    //var userDtos= ...
    mockMvc.perform(post("/users")
            .with(csrf())
            .contentType(APPLICATION_JSON)
            .content(userDtos))
            .andDo(print())
            .andExpect(status().isOk());
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Could you please also highlight the differences between two approaches , one where isFullyAuthenticated() is used & other where strategy is used. Is there any preferred one which one should follow?

Comment: When you specify the token repository as above the token will always be generated. The need for the authentication and csrf existence check is then not required. It appears as though Spring Security uses a different token repository by default. I had encountered the problem you documented and I found that the $({_csrf}) actually contained a token but it was one in which the creation of the token was deferred until  it was accessed. If this happens while the page is being generated data has already been placed in the response and an exception is thrown trying to store the token in the session.

Comment: Second approach where HttpSessionCsrfTokenRepository is used, did not work. Same error was coming, hence just went my approach & used if condition i.e. th:if="${_csrf}" mentioned in your first approach